# PL/pgSQL : can't use variable on the right side of `in` operator

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I'm writing a function using PostgreSQL 10 and I can't figure out how to extract a sub-query I use into a variable. My code looks like this

```
create function "is_valid_slot_task"() returns trigger as $$
<<block>>
declare
    schedule_id integer;
    ...
begin
    block.schedule_id := (select distinct c."schedule_id"
                          from "slot" as s
                          join "column" as c on c."column_id" = s."column_id"
                          where s."slot_id" = new."slot_id");
    if block.schedule_id
       in
       (select distinct c."schedule_id"
        from "slot_task" as st
        join "slot" as s on s."slot_id" = st."slot_id"
        join "column" as c on c."column_id" = s."column_id"
        where st."task_id" = new."task_id")
    ...
```

It works as expected (you can [try it here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=4621e1b7c87499bb746c19d435cc8a54)).

My question is, how could extract the sub-query on the right side of `in` into a variable in a way similar to this

```
create function "is_valid_slot_task"() returns trigger as $$
<<block>>
declare
    schedule_id integer;
    schedule_ids integer[];
    ...
begin
    block.schedule_id := (select distinct c."schedule_id"
                          from "slot" as s
                          join "column" as c on c."column_id" = s."column_id"
                          where s."slot_id" = new."slot_id");
    block.schedule_ids := (select distinct c."schedule_id"
                           from "slot_task" as st
                           join "slot" as s on s."slot_id" = st."slot_id"
                           join "column" as c on c."column_id" = s."column_id"
                           where st."task_id" = new."task_id");
    if block.schedule_id
       in
       block.schedule_ids
       ...
```

The difference is that I try to declare a variable to which I want to assign the result of the sub-query (a list/array/collection integers) and then I use this on the right side of the `in` operator.

This last version doesn't work, I get `SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "block" ...`. Here you can [see it in action](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=3a3bfcd462fcb2f626304cd2e3e2e640).

How could I make this work? What am I doing wrong? Is there a solution?

My goal is to reuse the result of the sub-query later on, to avoid typing the same-query multiple times and to understand why I couldn't do this. I also tried different data types in the declaration: `any`, `%ROWTYPE`, but I just couldn't understand what's going on.

Comment: @stickybit Well, I was under the impression that PL/SQL is a kind of standard_ish_ thing which is implemented by PL/pgSQL, but I'm not exactly sure at this point. The solution presented contains PostgreSQL specific stuff, but I was curious about what kind of syntax could be use to solve my problem in the general sense, either in PL/SQL or in PL/pgSQL (I presume I could have face the same issue in PL/SQL as well).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `schedule_ids` is an array, you should assign an array value to it using `array_agg()`. Next, use [`ANY (array expression)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.28.16) instead of `IN` operator:

```
block.schedule_ids := (select array_agg(distinct c."schedule_id")
                       from "slot_task" as st
                       join "slot" as s on s."slot_id" = st."slot_id"
                       join "column" as c on c."column_id" = s."column_id"
                       where st."task_id" = new."task_id");
if block.schedule_id = any (block.schedule_ids)
```

[DbFiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=9c54aab6c410e74b8de7d19d0cdc7dd4)